# Qt Quick: How to avoid code-repeating during similar GUI elements creation in QML?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml

First of all I would like to apologize for not having read all the QML documentation yet.
But I have to ask here, cause it makes me sleepless, so let's get to the point:

I have GUI element that repeats 9 times. These are rectangles containing Image and MouseArea (each one). The only property that distinguishes them from each other is their position in the Cartesian system.
The rest of properties are exactly the same for each item.

I have found this:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-repeater.html

But in meantime I have started thinking, is there in QML possibility of declaration user classes and then calling this class objects using constructor?

At the moment my code is a few hundred lines long, althought  my application seems to be very simply. I cannot even imagine, how it could look like if I'll start something more complicated and won't find method to make that shorter.

So the question is like in the title:
How to avoid code-repeating during similar GUI elements creation in QML?

Comment: You can create a new qml file then encapsulate a control(like the class) you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options to define QML object types, have a look at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html).

### Defining an Object Type with a QML File

> To create an object type, a QML document should be placed into a text
> file named as TypeName.qml where TypeName is the desired name of
> the type.

```
// ImageButton.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 100
    height: 100

    Image {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "test.png"
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: console.log("Button clicked!")
    }
}
```

Since the file is named ImageButton.qml, this can now be used as a type named ImageButton by any other QML file within the same directory.

```
// myapplication.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

ImageButton {}
```

### Defining an Object Type inline

You can use inline components to declare a new component inside of a file.

```
// myapplication.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

component ImageButton : Item {
    width: 100
    height: 100

    Image {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "test.png"
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: console.log("Button clicked!")
    }
}

ImageButton {}
```

### Use the [Component](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-component.html) QML Type

I would rather use one of the above options, because this option has some limitation in the usage of your custom components. I would use the Component QML Type if the component will only be used as a delegate. Here is a quote from the documentation:

> Sometimes, it can be inconvenient to create a new file for a type, for
> instance when reusing a small delegate in multiple views. If you don't
> actually need to expose the type, but only need to create an instance,
> Component is an option. But if you want to declare properties with the
> component types, or if you want to use it in multiple files, Component
> is not an option. In that case, you can use inline components.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned `Rectangle`, `MouseArea`, and `Image`, I wanted to make sure you check existing components, such as `ItemDelegate` and `Button` that support `background`, `icon`, `pressed` properties and have an `onClicked` signal.

In terms of render, not only is there `Repeater`, but there are `ListView` and `GridView` which also have support for flickable scrollbars.

In the following example, I created a `MyDelegate.qml` which contains a clickable delegate with a custom rectangular background and customizable icon and text whose 9 instances as controlled by the `ListModel`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement { txt: "one"; ico: "frown.svg"; icol: "red" }
        ListElement { txt: "two"; ico: "smile.svg"; icol: "green" }
        ListElement { txt: "three"; ico: "smile.svg"; icol: "green" }
        ListElement { txt: "four"; ico: "frown.svg"; icol: "red" }
        ListElement { txt: "five"; ico: "smile.svg"; icol: "green" }
        ListElement { txt: "six"; ico: "frown.svg"; icol: "red" }
        ListElement { txt: "seven"; ico: "smile.svg"; icol: "green" }
        ListElement { txt: "eight"; ico: "frown.svg"; icol: "red" }
        ListElement { txt: "nine"; ico: "frown.svg"; icol: "red" }
    }
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: listModel
        delegate: MyDelegate { }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
    }
}

// MyDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
ItemDelegate {
    width: ListView.view.width - 20
    background: Rectangle {
        color: pressed ? "orange" : index & 1 ? "#eee" : "#ddd"
    }
    text: txt
    icon.source: ico
    icon.color: icol
}

// smile.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M16 29.8A13.8 13.8 0 1 1 29.8 16 13.815 13.815 0 0 1 16 29.8zm0-26.6A12.8 12.8 0 1 0 28.8 16 12.815 12.815 0 0 0 16 3.2zm-4.5 10.6a1.2 1.2 0 0 0 .608-.168 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464-.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .278-.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0-1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.278-.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464-.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0-1.216 0 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.277.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0 1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .277.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464.431 1.2 1.2 0 0 0 .608.168zm9.608-.168a1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464-.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .278-.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0-1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.278-.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464-.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0-1.216 0 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.277.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0 1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .277.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0 1.216 0zm3.223 5.743l-.926-.379a7.863 7.863 0 0 1-7.39 4.976.166.166 0 0 0-.032 0 7.863 7.863 0 0 1-7.388-4.976l-.926.379a8.846 8.846 0 0 0 8.313 5.597.21.21 0 0 0 .035 0 8.848 8.848 0 0 0 8.314-5.597z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>

// frown.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M16 29.8A13.8 13.8 0 1 1 29.8 16 13.815 13.815 0 0 1 16 29.8zm0-26.6A12.8 12.8 0 1 0 28.8 16 12.815 12.815 0 0 0 16 3.2zm6.318 20.026l.692-.723c-3.604-3.451-10.418-3.452-14.02 0l.692.723c3.19-3.057 9.448-3.055 12.636 0zM11.5 13.8a1.2 1.2 0 0 0 .608-.168 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464-.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .278-.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0-1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.278-.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464-.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0-1.216 0 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.277.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0 1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .277.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464.431 1.2 1.2 0 0 0 .608.168zm9.608-.168a1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464-.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .278-.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0-1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.278-.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464-.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0-1.216 0 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.277.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0 1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .277.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0 1.216 0z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Of course, there are similar existing objects! Anyway is worth to start creation custom  types. To be honest, the last few days I started to seriously consider whether or not to specialize in Qt, althought it looks enormous. Giant library + learning new language